# How to change the separator of my Grafana CSV Export from Comma to Semicolon

Tags: typescript, csv, grafana

I have a custom plugin in Grafana 10 base on the table plugin. This plugin add a button to export the data of the table into a CSV file. It actually work fine but the data is separated with a comma like this :

```
2023-08-09 15:51:27,2.26
```

It's all in one column but the data is separated with a comma that will give me issue with other data.

This is the code that give me this result :

```
import React from 'react';
import { PanelOptions } from './models.gen';
import { Table, Button } from '@grafana/ui'
import { PanelProps, toCSV, DataFrame, dateTimeFormat } from '@grafana/data';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

interface Props extends PanelProps<PanelOptions> {}

export const OCBPanel: React.FC<Props> = ({ options, data, width, height }) => {
  const exportCsv = (dataFrame: DataFrame) => {
    const dataFrameCsv = toCSV([dataFrame]);
    const panelName = data.request?.targets[0].refId;

    const blob = new Blob([String.fromCharCode(0xfeff), dataFrameCsv], {
      type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8',
    });
    const fileName = `${panelName}-data-${dateTimeFormat(new Date())}.csv`;
    saveAs(blob, fileName);
  };

  const count = data.series?.length;
  const hasFields = data.series[0]?.fields.length;
  const datas = data.series[0];
  const nbOfLine = datas.length;

  if (!count || !hasFields) {
    return <div>No data</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Button style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 2, bottom: 1}} onClick={() => exportCsv(datas)}>
          Export CSV
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div style={{ paddingTop: 17 }}>
        <Table height={height - 45} width={width} data={datas} resizable={true} />
        <div>
          <p style={{ paddingTop: 3, paddingLeft: 8 }}>Nombre de lignes : {nbOfLine}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

So I already tried to change

```
const dataFrameCsv = toCSV([dataFrame]);
```

To

```
 const dataFrameCsv = toCSV([dataFrame],{delimiter:';'});
```

but when I download the CSV again, the data is show like this :
[image]

in two columns without semicolon

I can't just chose to replace all comma in the csv into semicolon because it will broke some data.

This is what I want :

```
2023-08-09 15:51:27;2.26
```

Edit :

So with the delimiter in the csv file I have those two columns but If I do a     **console.log(dataFrameCsv)** :

```
2023-08-10 03:00:47;68.3
```

I have what I want in console, but not in the csv file. Any reasons why ?

Comment: Couldn't you enforce proper value quotation (maybe with [`quoteChar`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v6.7/packages_api/data/csvconfig/#quotechar-property)) and keep commas as a delimiter?

Comment: Also, it is not entirely clear what screenshot from Excel should show. Could you replace it with plain text content of the file (opened in notepad-like app)?

Comment: @markalex I have data that contains comma and there's nothing I can do about that. So I can't force anything.

Comment: I meant force `toCSV` produce output in the form `"2023-08-09 15:51:27","2.26"`. This way commas allowed inside values.

Comment: @markalex this does not even work sadly